# How to use mapReader from Control.Monad.Reader for reader monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

I am trying to figure out that how to use `mapReader` from `Control.Monad.Reader`.

For example I have this reader monad

```
myReaderMonad :: Reader String Int
myReaderMonad = do
  string <- ask
  return (length string)
```

I can run it like this

```
>>> runReader myReaderMonad  "Saurabh"
>>> 7
```

Now I am trying to check the value returned by runReader is even or not.
Without using `mapReader` I can do like this

```
>>> even $ runReader myReaderMonad  "Saurabh"
>>> False
```

But I want to do this by using `mapReader`
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#v:mapReader

I tried the following but it is not working.

```
>>> mapReader even  myReaderMonad  "Saurabh"
>>> • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char] -> t’
                  with actual type ‘ReaderT
                                      String Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Bool’
    • The function ‘mapReader’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘(Int -> Bool)
                    -> Reader String Int
                    -> ReaderT String Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Bool’
      has only two
      In the expression: mapReader even myReaderMonad "Saurabh"
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = mapReader even myReaderMonad "Saurabh"
```

Please help me here.

Comment: You still need to use `runReader`. And think about what you're going to do with `"Saurabh"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapReader` doesn't suddenly turn your `Reader`-computation into a plain function, it just turns it into another `Reader`-computation.

The expression `mapReader even myReaderMonad` doesn't return a function to which you could feed "Saurabh" as an argument. Instead, it gives you a `Reader String Bool`.

Now that you have this new `Reader String Bool` value, you can give it a string using `runReader` and obtain a result:

```
> myEvenReader = mapReader even myReaderMonad
...
> runReader myEvenReader "Saurabh"
False
```

Or you can use it in some other way, for example put it through another `mapReader`:

```
> myOddReader = mapReader not myEvenReader
...
> runReader myOddReader "Saurabh"
True
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing that it returns another reader monad and I need to run it again. @Fyodor